# mongo aggregate how to choose ‘$graphLookup or $lookup’

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I don't know how to choose ‘$graphLookup or $lookup’ Other similar

I am looking forward to mongodb officially more complete documentation

example:

```
{parentId: 0, cid: 1, other: 'a'},
{parentId: 0, cid: 2, other: 'b'},
{parentId: 0, cid: 3, other: 'c'},

{parentId: 1, cid: 11, other: 'aa'},
{parentId: 2, cid: 12, other: 'ab'},
{parentId: 3, cid: 13, other: 'ac'},
```

result:

```
{
parentId: 0, cid: 1, other: 'a', 
  children: [
   {parentId: 1, cid: 11, other: 'aa'},
  ]
},{
parentId: 0, cid: 2, other: 'b',
  children: [
   {parentId: 2, cid: 12, other: 'ab'},
  ]
},{
parentId: 0, cid: 3, other: 'c',
  children: [
   {parentId: 3, cid: 13, other: 'ac'},
  ]
}
},
```

how do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use  [$graphLookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "parentId": {
        $eq: 0
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $graphLookup: {
      from: "collection",
      startWith: "$cid",
      connectFromField: "cid",
      connectToField: "parentId",
      as: "children"
    }
  }
])
```

[$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) is used to “joined” collection for processing.

Comment: The result of your doing this is
```
children: []
```
Thank you for your answer